# Why is ScrollMagic triggering on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

I have a timeline and scene set up with ScrollMagic, and 50% of the time it triggers when the page loads, and not where I have set my trigger to start on a specific div.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // init ScrollMagic Controller.
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var fadeAnim;
   // Animation 1
    fadeAnim = function() {
        var timeline = new TimelineMax();
        tl1.to('#animateThis1', 1,{ opacity: 1, marginTop: '0%', ease: Power1.easeOut},1)
        .to('#animateThis2', 1,{ opacity: 1, marginTop: '3%', ease: Power1.easeOut}, 1.5)
    }
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger", offset: -300})
    .setTween(fadeAnim)
    .addTo(controller);
```

Now the frustrating thing is that it works at times and then at other times it starts when the page is finished loading, so that by the time I scroll to #trigger the animation has already completed. Other times it works as expected.

I'm not sure am I missing something, I have searched on Google and my code seems similar to what is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to add an offset.Check that.Try using debugging options in [Scene](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#event:add) or
Try to use  [addInticator](http:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js) plugin to debug

Try to provide a codepen or plunker for others to check the issue.It is difficult to give a solution based on your current question

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was because of a conflict between the version of `ScrollMagic` and `jquery`.

For me, using any version of `ScrollMagic` != 1.3.0 resulted in the error you describe.

It's worth a shot to try using 1.3.0 instead, e.g.

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/1.3.0/jquery.scrollmagic.js`